# How do I set React State from an Asynchronous Mongo call?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm sure this must be a fairly common question, but I couldn't find a good up to date solution on Stack overflow...  Within the Domain of React/Meteor. I want to query a mongoDB to extract some information and then pass it into my react components State. Currently I'm querying mongoldb with a parent component and passing down to child component as props - however when the child component renders the mongoDB call has not yet returned so my props are undefined.

From various sources it seems like I need to implement an asynchronous javascript call to mongo and then callback to state. However I can't find any examples of this in the wild. Does anyone have a pattern for this? Finally - please jump  in if I am approaching this in the wrong way.

Any advice appreciated!

```
export default class GooleMapComponent extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)


this.state = {
  {position: {lat: this.props.mapParams.longitude, lng: this.props.mapParams.longitude},
  // this returns undefined a
   key: `goshi`,
   defaultAnimation: 2
 }
```

Comment: It depends on where you want to execute the request. If you want to perform something when a component is initially rendering, you can do it in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle as the reactjs docs suggest. What are you using for `http` calls? You can use something like `fetch` or `axios` and simply execute `setState()` within your http callback method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the parent component works properly, you have two options the way I see it:

1. You can have the parent component not render the child component while it doesn't have the props
2. You can have the child component work but show a 'loading' state while it doesn't have the correct props

To achieve 1:

define a method on your parent component called something like `renderGoogleMapComponent(mapParams)` (by the way you have a typo there, `Goole`)
which will render the child only if mapParams is defined:

```
renderGoogleMapComponent(mapParams){
    if(mapParams != undefined){
        return <GoogleMapComponent mapParams={mapParams}/>
    }
```

Then in the `render` of the parent component call

```
renderGoogleMapComponent(whereverYouGetThoseMapParamsMaybe this.state.mapParams?)
```

where you used to have

```
<GoogleMapComponent mapParams={whereverYouGetThoseMapParamsMaybe this.state.mapParams?}/>
```

To achieve 2:

In the render method of the child component, check if you are getting the props:

```
render(){
    if(this.props.mapParams != undefined){
        //your render logic here
    } else {
       return <div>Loading map data</div>
    }
```

Note: there is no need for storing the props in the state, really why would you?
Also: in the constructor `this.props` is undefined, just use `props`

In 1. You could also have the parent component do the 'loading' display, but that is a different question, and you should obviously adjust this to best serve the user

Comment: Thanks narvoxx, this is exactly what I was looking for. Very elegant.